# having so much trouble trying to see why the following is true

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

For any function $f$ and any $x∈Dom(f)$, if for any neighbourhood $S$ of $x$,

$\qquad f(t)=0$ for some $t∈S$

$\qquad f(u)=1$ for some $u∈S$

then $ f$ is discontinuous at $x$.

Why is this true? I find it very hard to understand it :(.

Comment: Why are you writing the statement like that?

Comment: Computer scientist? :D

Comment: What definition of continuous are you using?

Comment: What are you assuming about the domain of $f$? For example, if the domain of $f$ is discrete, then every function out of it is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think dkuper gave the canonical answer, let me provide my own.
I think we both presume that the codomain of the function is $\mathbb{R}$ though in my solution $T_1$ space will suffice.

Let $a$ be either $0$ or $1$ so that $a \neq f(x)$.  $f^{-1}(a)$ is closed and does not contain $x$. This is a contradiction because if we take $S=X\setminus f^{-1}(a)$ then $S$ contains an element of $f^{-1}(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the fact that $f$ is continuous at $x$ means that for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a neighbourhood of $x$ such that for every $t$ in the neighbourhood, $|f(x)-f(t)|<\epsilon$.

Here it suffices to take for instance $\epsilon=1/3$ to reach a contradiction: such a neighbourhood cannot exist, since we would know that it contains some $t,u$ with $f(t)=0$ and $f(u)=1$. This would imply $|f(x)-1|<1/3$ and $|f(x)-0|<1/3$, which is impossible.

The condition for continuity in $x$ cannot be met, so $f$ is discontinuous at $x$.